# How do I avoid a variable resetting at the beginning of a function?

Tags: python

I'm new to python so I'm sorry if the code is very bad. But, I am making a basic slot machine game and I'm trying to implement a credit system. You start off with 50 credits and it requires 25 to spin. It works, but the problem is, my spin is in a function. And, because it is in a function it resets the credits each time it spins again. I am using an if statement to calculate the credits after a spin.

Important to note, I am using a variable named `totalcredits` to calculate the actual credits. This is because if I try to use the `credits` variable in my if statement I get the error: `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'credits' referenced before assignment`.

This makes sense because I am in effect creating a loophole of credits, at least I think. So I've been trying to think of a workaround to stop resetting the credits but it is outside my range of knowledge. I've tried global variables and a few other things that didn't work. Here is my code:

```
import random

credits = 50
spindeduct = 25

win1 = 10
win2 = 40
win3 = 30
#win1, which is temporarily a "X" is worth 10 credits. So if the slots landed "X:X:X" you would get 10 credits. win2 is worth 40 credits (a "7"), and win 3 is worth 30 credits (a "Cherry"). Each spin deducts 25 from your credits
def spin():

  z = random.randint(1, 3)
  x = random.randint(1, 3)
  y = random.randint(1, 3)
  #1 = X
  #2 = 7
  #3 = Cherry
  print("\n")
  print(z)
  print(x)
  print(y)

  #this chunky if statement calculates the amount of credits the player should have, it technically works but the credits is reset every time
  if z == 1 and x == 1 and y == 1:
    print("\nYou got a small win! + 10 Credits!")
    totalcredits = credits - spindeduct + win1
  elif z == 2 and x == 2 and y == 2:
    print("\nYou won! + 40 Credits!")
    totalcredits = credits - spindeduct + win2
  elif z == 3 and x == 3 and y == 3:
    print("\nYou won! + 30 Credits!")
    totalcredits = credits - spindeduct + win3
  else:
    print("\nYou lost!")
    totalcredits = credits - spindeduct

  #printcredits is a janky workaround to prevent errors when telling the user the amount of credits they have
  printcredits = totalcredits
  print("You have " + str(printcredits) + " credits.")
  v = input("\nWould you like to spin again? Y/N: ")

  #if the player doesn't have enough credits to spin, they can no longer play
  if totalcredits >= 25:
    print("\nYou have enough credits to spin again!")
  else:
    print("You do not have enough credits to spin again!")
    quit()


  if v == "Y":
    spin()
  elif v == "y":
    spin()
  else:
    print("Stopped")
    quit()
  
  

print("Slot Simulator")

a = input("Would to like to spin some slots? (50 Credits) Y/N: ")

if a == "y":
  spin()
elif a == "Y":
  spin()
else:
  print(Stopped)
```

Comment: Global variables should work.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a big deal to "use a global variable", especially in a small file (i.e. a Python module) -- it automatically gets namespaced to that module.

```py
gamestate = {'credits': 0}

def increment():
    gamestate['credits'] += 1

increment()
print(gamestate)
# gamestate == {'credits': 1}
```

This has its limits as code grows larger & more complex though, e.g.  multiple modules. An alternative would be to pass state into your functions:

```py
gamestate = {'credits': 0}

def increment(state):
  state['credits'] += 1

increment(gamestate)
print(gamestate)
# {'credits': 1}
```

And sometimes the state changes get so complex and hard to keep track of that it helps to avoid mutations by creating new copies instead:

```py
gamestate = {'credits': 0}

def increment(state):
  return {'credits': state['credits'] + 1}

new_state = increment(gamestate)
print(gamestate)
# {'credits': 0}

print(new_state)
# {'credits': 1}

gamestate = new_state  # can still mutate in the end, in a single place
print(gamestate)
# {'credits': 1}
```

---

A word about why I'm using a `dict` "`gamestate`":

```py
credits = 0  # I could use a global int

# but global variables normally can't be modified inside functions:
def wont_work():
    credits = credits + 1


def declare_global():
    global credits  # you could declare that it's global for modification
    credits += 1    # same as credits = credits + 1

    other_num = 10

    # but many lines of code later, it can get confusing
    # just looking at these two lines, can you tell which is global?
    other_num += 1  # only changes inside this function
    credits += 1    # affects other functions using the same variable!


# dicts are naturally modifiable (i.e. mutable) containers
gamestate = {'credits': 0}  # a dict holding an int

# note that global var `gamestate` isn't changing
def increment():
    other_num = 10

    # It's pretty clear which is making a change "somewhere else"
    other_num += 1
    gamestate['credits'] += 1  # changes contents of `dict`
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit your code like so:

```
import random

credits = 50
spindeduct = 25

win1 = 10
win2 = 40
win3 = 30
#win1, which is temporarily a "X" is worth 10 credits. So if the slots landed "X:X:X" you would get 10 credits. win2 is worth 40 credits (a "7"), and win 3 is worth 30 credits (a "Cherry"). Each spin deducts 25 from your credits
def spin():
  global credits
  z = random.randint(1, 3)
  x = random.randint(1, 3)
  y = random.randint(1, 3)
  #1 = X
  #2 = 7
  #3 = Cherry
  print("\n")
  print(z)
  print(x)
  print(y)

  #this chunky if statement calculates the amount of credits the player should have, it technically works but the credits is reset every time
  if z == 1 and x == 1 and y == 1:
    print("\nYou got a small win! + 10 Credits!")
    credits = credits - spindeduct + win1
  elif z == 2 and x == 2 and y == 2:
    print("\nYou won! + 40 Credits!")
    credits = credits - spindeduct + win2
  elif z == 3 and x == 3 and y == 3:
    print("\nYou won! + 30 Credits!")
    credits = credits - spindeduct + win3
  else:
    print("\nYou lost!")
    credits = credits - spindeduct

  #printcredits is a janky workaround to prevent errors when telling the user the amount of credits they have
  printcredits = credits
  print("You have " + str(printcredits) + " credits.")
  v = input("\nWould you like to spin again? Y/N: ")

  #if the player doesn't have enough credits to spin, they can no longer play
  if credits >= 25:
    print("\nYou have enough credits to spin again!")
  else:
    print("You do not have enough credits to spin again!")
    quit()


  if v == "Y":
    spin()
  elif v == "y":
    spin()
  else:
    print("Stopped")
    quit()
  
  
print("Slot Simulator")

a = input("Would to like to spin some slots? (50 Credits) Y/N: ")

if a == "y":
  spin()
elif a == "Y":
  spin()
else:
  print("Stopped")
```

You need to save the new credits to `credits` instead of `totalcredits`.

Your code works great as is if you just change every instance of `totalcredits` to `credits` and make credits global within the function (see code above).

Comment: Oh yeah, this worked. Thanks!

Comment: @titianderp Great! I would greatly appreciate an accepted answer if it helped!

Answer (score -1):

Right now, your function and the rest of your code have no way of communicating. Your code can’t give the function any information, and your function can’t return your code any information. We can do this simply by passing in `credits` as a parameter and returning it at the end. Another thing is you appeared to have most of your game loop inside the function itself, which generally isn’t ideal. You can see how you would remake it [here](https://pastebin.com/65WjQVti).